# Android Audio Recording Garbled

Tags: android, audio

We have a long-running android app that can record audio when a button is pressed. Upon a fresh install, the audio recording works as expected.

I left the app running overnight and attempted a recording again this morning. The audio sounded like this:

https://soundcloud.com/joe-mccall-7/our-android-app-one-through

I was thinking maybe the app had put the sound processor in a weird state, so I installed an audio recording app from the Play store and this was the result:

https://soundcloud.com/joe-mccall-7/audio-recorder-pro-one-through

Switching back to our app and recording results in the same garbled audio. Here's where we instantiate the recording object:

```
// the recording rate in samples per second (hz)
public static final int RECORDING_RATE = 11025;

// we will be recording and playing back as mono with PCM 16 bit encoding.
private static final int RECORDING_CHANNEL = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int ENCODING_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

// the buffer size is determined by the recording rate, channel and format
private static int RECORDING_BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
        RECORDING_RATE, RECORDING_CHANNEL, ENCODING_FORMAT) * 2;

// the audio recorder instance used for microphone input
private static AudioRecord recorder =
        new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDING_RATE, RECORDING_CHANNEL, ENCODING_FORMAT,
                RECORDING_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Later in the code we have a long-running thread that reads audio from the recorder instance and writes it to a `BufferedOutputStream` object:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename);

// as long as the user has not canceled the streaming...
while (transmitting) {

    // read the data into the buffer
    int read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

    // write the buffer to the output stream
    bos.write(buffer);
}

// close the buffer and write the wav file
```

I don't see how the issue could be the writing of the wav file, considering that a fresh install of the app records several audio files just fine.

When I force-stop the app and start it again, recordings go back to normal:

https://soundcloud.com/joe-mccall-7/force-stop-and-restart-one-through-ten

So what do you theorize would cause the wav file to become garbled like that?